# Sorting and calculating in linux

Tags: shell

```
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.el7.x Wed Oct 26 15:12 - 22:43  (07:30)    
root     :0           :0               Wed Oct  5 05:01 - 05:31  (00:29)    
(unknown :0           :0               Wed Oct  5 05:01 - 05:01  (00:00)    
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.el7.x Tue Oct  4 23:01 - 05:31  (06:29)    
root     :0           :0               Wed Oct  5 04:56 - 04:58  (00:01)    
(unknown :0           :0               Wed Oct  5 04:56 - 04:56  (00:00)    
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.el7.x Tue Oct  4 22:55 - 04:58  (06:02)
```

Anyone can show me how i can write a command in linux that counts the number of logins each user did and calculate the total number of time spent. Project it onto the screen that shows something this.

```
User root logged in a total of ?? times with a total of mins/hours logged
User unknown logged in a total of ?? times with a total of mins/hours logged.
```

Comment: Looks suspiciously like a homework assignment.

Comment: What have you tried so far so we can get an idea of just how much help you need.

Comment: This provides the total of logins for every user: `for i in $(awk '{print $1}' login_file.txt | sort -u); do echo -e $i: ; grep $i login_file.txt | wc -l; done`, from there try to get your desired outputs and ask if you have any specific question.

Answer (score 0):

```
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.el7.x Wed Oct 26 15:12 - 22:43  (07:30)    
root     :0           :0               Wed Oct  5 05:01 - 05:31  (00:29)    
(unknown :0           :0               Wed Oct  5 05:01 - 05:01  (00:00)    
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.el7.x Tue Oct  4 23:01 - 05:31  (06:29)    
root     :0           :0               Wed Oct  5 04:56 - 04:58  (00:01)    
(unknown :0           :0               Wed Oct  5 04:56 - 04:56  (00:00)    
reboot   system boot  3.10.0-327.el7.x Tue Oct  4 22:55 - 04:58  (06:02)
```

considering the above detail is in a file:

```
for i in `awk '{print $1}' test_login |sort|uniq`;
 do
         count=`grep -c $i test_login`
        sum=0;
        for j in `grep $i test_login|awk '{print $NF}'|cut -c 2-6`;
         do
                 var=`echo $j | awk -F: '{print ($1 * 60) + $2}'`;
                 sum=$((sum+var));
        done
        ((hour=$sum/60))
        ((min=$sum-$hour*60))
        echo "User $i logged in a total of $count times with a total of $hour:$min logged"
  done
```

test_login : file which contains log of all users.

Comment: What have i done wrongly. I am using last for capturing of the logins instead of a file.

Comment: ./totallog.sh: line 4: 5: command not found
User itdp04 logged in a total of  times with a total of 47:5 logged
./totallog.sh: line 4: 31: command not found
User reboot logged in a total of  times with a total of 458:22 logged
./totallog.sh: line 4: 540: command not found
User root logged in a total of  times with a total of 136:8 logged
./totallog.sh: line 4: 31: command not found
User (unknown logged in a total of  times with a total of 2:17 logged
./totallog.sh: line 4: 1: command not found
User wtmp logged in a total of  times with a total of 16:0 logged

Comment: #!/bin/bash
for i in `last |gawk '{print $1}' |sort|uniq`
do
         count= `last |grep -c $i`
         sum=0;
         for j in `last |grep $i |gawk '{print $NF}'|cut -c 2-6`;
         do
                 var=`echo $j | awk -F: '{print ($1 * 60) + $2}'`;
                 sum=$((sum+var));
        done
 ((hour=$sum/60))
        ((min=$sum-$hour*60))
        echo "User $i logged in a total of $count times with a total of $hour:$min logged"
  done

Comment: Thanks for your help. I managed to get it to work with last with your codes.

Comment: Glad it worked. If helped, mark question as answered.